# Using product list widget to just show price?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-list, widgets

How can I use a product list widget to just show the price of the product on an cms page.

Comment: You can ask it in comments in your last question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226854/showing-certain-product-price-on-an-cms-page

Comment: You can ask the same question to your first question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226317/how-can-i-make-a-cms-pages-product-price-dynamic/226325?noredirect=1#comment315276_226325